# Angular Routes not mapping properly for lazy loading

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-router

So I have an app with multiple modules that has routes properly put in place, and each module has it's own routes. Everything works fine, until I try to implement lazy loading.

Previous State:

example module

```
export const EXAMPLE_ROUTES: Routes = [
        { path: 'new', component: AddOpportunityComponent },
        { path: ':id', component: OpportunityProfileComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'edit/sdg-info', component: SdgInfoComponent
                }

            ]}
];
```

I import this EXAMPLE_ROUTES in example module

Now I have root level routing as

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
    { path: 'example', component: ExampleComponent, children: [...EXAMPLE_ROUTES], canActivate: [AuthGuard, OnboardedGuard] },
];

export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, {enableTracing: true});
```

With this setup it works fine

After trying to have lazy loading

example module

```
const EXAMPLE_ROUTES: Routes = [
        { path: 'new', component: AddOpportunityComponent },
        { path: ':id', component: OpportunityProfileComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'edit/sdg-info', component: SdgInfoComponent
                }
            ]}
];

export const exampleRouting = RouterModule.forChild(EXAMPLE_ROUTES);
```

and app routing becomes

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
    { path: 'example', loadChildren: './example/example.module#ExampleModule',  canActivate: [AuthGuard, OnboardedGuard] }

];

export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, {enableTracing: true});
```

The problem I'm facing is, the example route works fine, now the /search route breaks, as the router for some reason tries to match it with opportunity route (path: ':id')

What might be going wrong here?

Comment: Can you share your app.module.ts please? Is your `ExampleModule` imported in app.module? If it is declared in your imports, you have to remove it, because this module is getting loaded asynchronously.

Comment: best would be to share a stackblitz example

Comment: @SplitterAlex Thanks so much bro, that was the issue, I forgot to remove it from app module

Comment: I am glad I could help :) I created an answer with some explanation why your `search` url got matched with your route `:id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can occoure when you first implement your `FeatureModule` in your `RootModule` and after a given time you decide you want to load this `FeatureModule` lazy via `loadChildren` and you forgot to remove `FeatureModule` from your imports in your `RootModule`.

In your case your Routing Configuration will look something like this after compilation (PSEUDO-CODE):

```js
const Routes_CONFIG = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: 'example', loadChildren: './example/example.module#ExampleModule',  canActivate: [AuthGuard, OnboardedGuard] }
  { path: 'new', component: AddOpportunityComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: OpportunityProfileComponent,
      children: [
        { path: 'edit/sdg-info', component: SdgInfoComponent }
      ]
  }
]
```

In your case, when you just enter /search you will match `:id` `OpportunityProfileComponent`. That's because the router accepts the first route that matches a navigation request path.